# I need to get CertificationPath from an X509 Certificate using C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509

I am using C#. I was able to get Issuer using .Issuer attribute but cannot find any such for Certification Path

Comment: Open certificate with notepad and see the structure.  If certificate is xml that you can use xml library to parser certificate.

Comment: Certificate is in base64 format

Comment: If it is base64 than use Convert.FromBase64String(string).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A certification path or trust path (etc.) is not part of the certificate itself. It is formed from a **trust store** containing **trust anchors**, and a set of intermediate certificates. The certificate you have includes the authority key identifier and issuer name so that such a trust path can be build. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/51558/2651) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
// configure chain.ChainPolicy as you see fit
...
bool trustworthy = chain.Build(cert);
```

Now `chain.ChainElements` represents the certification path, with `chain.ChainElements[i].Certificate` being the certificate thereof.  If the return value of `chain.Build` is `false` then something's not kosher with the chain, and `chain.ChainStatus`/`chain.ChainElements[i].ChainElementStatus` will tell you what.